# New Project - Invalid NuGet version string: 'VERSION'

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

When I create a new project from the scratch I am actually facing this compilation issue:

[image: Error description]

In order to solve it, I have to edit each project properties, on the package section and change the default value for "Package Version" configuration. I have to change it from 'VERSION' to some valid version number like 1.0.0.0.

[image: Package version default value]

This is also happening when I checkout code from some of my coworkers, who don't have this issue.

Is there a way to solve it? Is there an environment configuration missing on my local computer?

I am actually using Windows 10 x64, and Visual Studio 2019, but it also fails on vs2017.

Comment: if you cd to the directory where your project is and run `dotnet --info` from the command line, what version of the SDK is it using?  If you create a project from the command line (`dotnet new console`), can you build that project, or does it fail in the same way that VS new projects fail?

Comment: Restart the VS, create a new .net core project and the same error occurs?  According to your pic above, if you create a new project, some info like authors and company have been set by default, do you use some setting like nuget.config or Directory.Build.props?

Comment: I am not using anything in particular. That default info is just for this project, if I start a new project from the scratch, the same happens.

Comment: As what zivkan suggests, use a dotnet command to check the property values. The value in the project=>properties are corresponding to the value in .csproj. I think something overwrites the package version value in your .csproj which results in the error.

Answer (score 2):

.NET uses MSBuild to build projects, which means that all .NET project files are just MSBuild files. MSBuild has an option to pre-process the file into a single file (evaluate all imports, and it conveniently puts xml comments saying the filename the contents were imported from). So, either start a "Developer command prompt", cd to your project directory and run `msbuild -pp:pp.txt`, or from any command prompt, cd to your project directory and run `dotnet msbuild -pp:pp.txt`, then open your favourite text or XML editor and search `pp.txt` for "VERSION". Once you found it, scroll up until it tells you which file defined that property.

My guess is that you have a [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file somewhere on your filesystem somewhere above where you create all your projects that defines the `Version` property to the value `VERSION`.

Comment: Hi @zivkan, thanks for answering. I executed your instructions and I could not even find "VERSION" string nor where "Version" is coming from.
This is happening with my old VS2017 as well as with my new VS2019, no matter if I am using Net Core or just Net Framework

Comment: Another tool to debug MSBuild issues is running `msbuild -bl`, which writes a `msbuild.binlog` that you can read with the [MSBuild Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com/). It'll show you the task that failed, then you can use the tree and search to see what the value was and maybe track where the property was changed. But honestly I'd be really surprised if the pp file doesn't contain it. That suggests that your .NET Core SDK is broken and a task is using a value that was not passed to it. the binlog can help track that down.

Answer (score 2):

On the system where the Restore is running, check if you have a pre-configured Environment Variable with name 'version'.

MS Build sometimes picks this value to restore the builds.

I was not able to understand where the invalid value 'latest' is coming from. We tried debugging Directory.build.props files for global project property. Even .csproj had no typos or version values specified(In my case version was set to latest, for you it could be null or any any value that is invalid per MS Build.)

Updating version from 15 to 16 didn't help either.

We checked system environment variables and found that one of the variable was 'VERSION' which was set to latest. Removing this variable (eg, unset version) resolved the issue for us.

Comment: Your answer must contain an example in code ...
After all, this question is old ...